# Configuring Spring LDAP via application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

Spring seems to have some predefined ldap properties that are available in the **application.properties** file, such as

```
spring.ldap.urls=
spring.ldap.base=
spring.ldap.username
spring.ldap.password=
```

However, it seems that you still have to create a security configuration, where you have to define those properties in code, as Spring complains that it can´t find any AuthenticationProvider

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchBase("ou=people")
                .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
                .contextSource().root("dc=baeldung,dc=com")
                .ldif("classpath:users.ldif");
    }

}
```

Source https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-ldap

**How can you use those properties without creating an extra configuration where you have to define them again?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to redefine those properties because that Property is for creating **DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource**
However, you can also read these properties from application.properties instead of rewriting

```
   @Value("${spring.ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrls;

    @Value("${spring.ldap.base}")
    private String ldapBase;

    @Value("${spring.ldap.userDnPatterns}")
    private String userDnPatterns;

    @Value("${spring.ldap.groupSearchBase:ou=groups}")
    private String groupSearchBase;


 @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userSearchBase(ldapBase)
                    .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                    .groupSearchBase(groupSearchBase)    
                    .userDnPatterns(userDnPatterns)

        }
```

Besides these security Spring also create LdapTemplate Bean from these properties